# "ui is not declared in current scope" error

Tags: godot

I just started development for a game I have to design for school. When using gd in the script to make the character move right I get an error:

```
extends KinematicBody2D 

var motion = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):

    if input.is_action_pressed(ui.right):
        motion.x = 100

    move_and_slide(motion)
```

This is the line that is giving me problems

```
if input.is_action_pressed(ui.right):
```

and it keeps saying that ui is not declared in the current scope

Comment: This is a pure syntax error. Generally errors like this can be solved by just [searching for the text of the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=godot+not+declared+in+the+current+scope) or [reading the documentation for the method you're using and following the examples](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html). When you find yourself really stuck on a syntax error, [check on our general programming sister site StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) — since these questions do not need special game expertise to answer, you'll find answers faster there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this should be a problem. Just do what Mertle told you to do.

"Who the heck is Mertle?" you might ask. "I don't know anyone by that name!"

That's exactly what the compiler is telling you:

> "not declared in the current scope"

is the compiler's way of saying "I don't know who you're talking about. Who is this `ui` person who can tell me about `.right`? You haven't introduced us yet!"

You've used a new name that you haven't introduced before in this conversation (scope), so the compiler has no idea who you mean.

In fact, `ui` is not an object that the compiler can ask for a `.right` member.

`"ui.right"` is a string of text that you want it to pass to the `is_action_pressed` function as-is.

To pass a string, you *must* put double-quotation marks around it, so the compiler knows to treat it as a blob of plain text, not an expression or variable to parse and evaluate.

So, replace this with:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
```

...[as shown in the Godot documentation on Input events](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html).

As a general rule, when following a programming guide, every character is important. You can't leave any out. So check your examples carefully to make sure you typed out everything. The capitalization of `Input` is important too!